# Filtrar y eliminar propiedad de un array

Tags: javascript, typescript

Tengo un array formado de la siguiente manera:

```
descriptionAndItem = [
    {
      description: 'Transaction A',
      items: [
        { status: 1, description: 'Item A', code: 4 },
        { status: 1, description: 'Item B', code: 3 },
      ],
    },
    {
      description: 'Transaction B',
      items: [{ status: 0, description: 'Item C', code: 8 }],
    },
    {
      description: 'Transaction C',
      items: [
        { status: 1, description: 'Item D', code: 4 },
        { status: 0, description: 'Item E', code: 8 },
      ],
    },
  ];
```

De esa información debo filtrar solo los que tengan el estado del ítem igual a uno, para ello uso la función `filter` y `find` de la siguiente forma:

```
let filterData = this.descriptionAndItem.filter((x: any) =>
    x.items.find((y: any) => y.status === 1)
);
```

Pero cuando hay mas de un ítem y solo uno de ellos tiene el estado igual a uno, el filtrado muestra también el ítem que tiene el estado igual a cero. Como podría hacer el filtrado para que no muestre ese ítem o lo elimine.

[image: item]

Demo: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-vi1pvt)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podrías recorrer tu arreglo padre mediante **[reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)**, y dentro de ésta utilizar `filter` para obtener los elementos que cumplen las condiciones.

```js
const descriptionAndItem = [{
    description: 'Transaction A',
    items: [{
        status: 1,
        description: 'Item A',
        code: 4
      },
      {
        status: 1,
        description: 'Item B',
        code: 3
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    description: 'Transaction B',
    items: [{
      status: 0,
      description: 'Item C',
      code: 8
    }],
  },
  {
    description: 'Transaction C',
    items: [{
        status: 1,
        description: 'Item D',
        code: 4
      },
      {
        status: 0,
        description: 'Item E',
        code: 8
      },
    ],
  },
];

(() => {
  const result = descriptionAndItem.reduce((prev, curr) => {
    const aux = curr.items.filter(i => i.status === 1)
    
    if (aux.length > 0) {
      const add = { ...curr, items: aux }
      prev.push(add)
    }
    
    return prev
  }, [])

  console.log(result)
})()
```

La clave está dentro del `if`, en el cual creamos una constante que tendrá el elemento que se esta recorriendo, y a ese elemento le adjuntamos sólo los *items* que corresponden.

Nos comentas que tal te va.

Answer (score 0):

La mejor forma en mi opinión es usando `.reduce`, pero siguiendo la lógica que utilizaste, deberías usar otro `.filter` dentro del `.filter` (en lugar de `.find`). Porque son dos cosas las que quieres filtrar, "transacciones" e "items". Lo que sucede es que `.filter` no altera cada elemento, es solo `true` o `false`, está completo o no está. Pero esto no impide que lo podamos altererar manualmente antes de decirle que tal o cual elemento será "admitido" (`true`). Entonces se podría hacer:

```js
const descriptionAndItem = [{"description":"Transaction A","items":[{"status":1,"description":"Item A","code":4},{"status":1,"description":"Item B","code":3}]},{"description":"Transaction B","items":[{"status":0,"description":"Item C","code":8}]},{"description":"Transaction C","items":[{"status":1,"description":"Item D","code":4},{"status":0,"description":"Item E","code":8}]}];

let filterData = descriptionAndItem.filter((x, i, o) =>
  (o[i].items = x.items.filter(y => y.status === 1)) && x.items.length
);

console.log(filterData);
```

Donde el tercer parámetro del primer `.filter` es el array original, es lo mismo que si usaramos `descriptionAndItem`.

De esta manera, en cada iteración del primer `.filter` alteramos el array original (representado con `o`) antes de decidir si va a estar o no, dicha alteración es otro `.filter`. Luego de la alteración, si resulta que `items` tiene cero elementos, no se va a incluír el padre de `items` en el array final.

Comment: Duda, el alterar el objeto original no iría en contra de la inmutabilidad propia de la programa funcional? Nice answer!

Comment: @PauloUrbanoRivera Si, no quedaría autocontenido. Modifique el código de manera de usar el tercer paŕametro, asi da una sensación de que está autocontenido, pero en verdad es lo mismo que usar el objeto original. Osea el problema es que al alterar arrays casi siempre hay que hacer cosas poco intuitivas en JavaScript. De paso, yo usaría `reduce` aunque sea aún menos intuitiva.